# GWT - TreeTable?

Tags: gwt, flextable, treetable

I'm looking for a way to extend GWT FlexTable or CellTable to a "TreeTable". I want a table with expandable rows, and I want to be able to get the data from the sever when it's needed. So I don't want to populate the whole table (all levels) from the start.

Is it best to use a FlexTable or a CellTable to start with? Or are there any examples/plugins on the web for this?

All ideas and tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a  [`TreeTable widget`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/TreeTable) at Google Web Toolkit Incubator . Here is the [demo](http://google-web-toolkit-incubator.googlecode.com/svn/branches/dflorey/tableAddons/demo/TreeTableDemo/TreeTableDemo.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've seen this but I haven't found any working code for it, have you?